# dataTables - how to make all columns orderable on 'draw.dt'

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a dataset which is retrieved into a dataTable via Ajax and there's a time delay which means the user could perform actions before it has loaded. I have to load this dataset all at once, so I can't use serverside processing to serve it in chunks this time.

I'm using dataTables Buttons for xls download on it, which I'm disabling until the dataset arrives, and then re-enabling. If I didn't do this, the user could download an empty spreadsheet before the ajax request completes. So, for the buttons, I've coded it like this:

```
buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
            titleAttr: 'Download to Excel',
            enabled: false
        },
    ],
```

then:

```
table.on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    table.buttons().enable();
});
```

I need to do the same with orderable columns because, if orderable columns are clicked before the data has loaded, the message displayed changes from 'Loading' to 'No data available in table' (understandably), but it's not a great user experience.

I'm setting every column as `orderable: false` like this:

```
columns: [
        {
            data: 'myData', 
            orderable: false, // all columns are set to false like this
        },
```

That works, it sets all of the columns so they can't be ordered. What I can't do is to make them all orderable after the data has loaded.

What I hoped would be possible is something like this, but it / nothing I try will work:

```
table.on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    table.columns().orderable().enable();
});
```

Any ideas? If I have to enable each column individually then that's okay too, I can't find a way to do that either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that setting `orderable: false` during initialization, then changing it later with `table.columns().orderable().enable();` would not work is that `orderable: false` is an **initialization option**. Due to the way DataTables works, you **can not change initialization options after initialization is complete**. This means you need to find some other way of disabling ordering while the data is loading.

Personally, if this is just the initial load, I would just hide the table with `style="display: none;"` until you can call the initComplete callback, then just call `$(...).show();`. If you don't want to just hide the entire table, you could selectively hide the header (maybe `$.("#table thead").hide();`), and show them after the load.

With the site I am developing, we have a similar situation where some 50k rows are loaded in at once. I use [$.blockUI()](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) to put a custom popup blocker over the table while its performing the ajax call. I think this solution has the best UI experience. You can use `$.blockUI()` to selectively apply a blocking modal over the table, with a custom loading message.